# Unable to install shopify-cli on Windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems, shopify, shopify-app

I was trying to follow [this link](https://shopify.github.io/shopify-app-cli/getting-started/install/#rubygem-all-platforms) here to install shopify-cli on my Windows 10 system.

I installed Ruby via **chocolatey**:

```
choco install ruby
```

Then I downloaded zipped version of rubygems and ran the setup through command:

```
ruby setup.rb
```

Then I tried installing the shopify app CLI through this command:

```
gem install shopify-cli
```

I ended up getting error and the error asked me to install [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) which I did.

I then once again tried to install **shopify-cli** but now hit the wall with this error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> gem install shopify-cli
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing shopify-cli:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/tools/ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.3.1/ext/shopify-cli
C:/tools/ruby27/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/tools/ruby27/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20201009-14664-r6pzlb.rb extconf.rb

current directory: C:/tools/ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.3.1/ext/shopify-cli
make "DESTDIR=" clean
current directory: C:/tools/ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.3.1/ext/shopify-cli
make "DESTDIR="
make failedNo such file or directory - make "DESTDIR="

Gem files will remain installed in C:/tools/ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.3.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/tools/ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.7.0/shopify-cli-1.3.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Same error happening even in Ubuntu

Comment: in my case on ubuntu this was due to forgot to install ruby on my machine and on top the latest ruby for my os was missing such library https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033027/jules

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So the problem was that I was using Chocolatey to install Ruby and then seperately trying to install MSYS2. Instead with the help of [this link](https://shopify.github.io/shopify-app-cli/getting-started/), I simply navigated to the [**ruby devkit** download site](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) and downloaded from there. This ensured MSYS2 gets installed via package as well. Then I also uninstalled **ruby gems** and tried re-installing it again and that worked as well.

Finally the command to install the **ruby-cli** worked:

```
gem install shopify-cli
Fetching shopify-cli-1.3.1.gem
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed shopify-cli-1.3.1
Parsing documentation for shopify-cli-1.3.1
Installing ri documentation for shopify-cli-1.3.1
Done installing documentation for shopify-cli after 13 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `ruby-dev` or `ruby-devel` for example first and then try again with

```
sudo apt-get install /Downloads/shopify-cli-2.6.3.deb
```

This should work